# Ways to stop other android applications from identifying my application?

Tags: android, security

We have developed a payment application with native android to compete in the local market. Our competitors have made it so that when their applications detect ours, theirs automatically disables itself. The problem is that our users use their applications as well so we wanted our application to be unidentifiable by the other apps.
Our solutions for this have been distributing our app manually instead of playstore and generating a unique bundle id for each individual user.

What else can we do to get around this?

Comment: Going by the manual route will only kill your application or business as you will never be able to onboard the users for long. Also if your competitor disables itself what is the problem they are the ones loosing clientele

Comment: Our users want to use both. If they have to choose they will choose our competitions because they have been in the market longer, hence their strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

till Android 10 any app can list ALL apps installed on device. starting Android 11 there are [some limitations](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) and by default you can't list all apps, so you are "safe". BUT 3rd-party may request [`QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/package-visibility#all-apps) permission and will detect your app as well. note that [Google Play Store have special policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779) for such apps, not every app may be published with it

still your app may be detected when it will use this 3rd-party apps API/`Service` (depends on way for access) and then it will lock itself

Comment: Not stealing anything.

Comment: well, if owner clearly refuses you to use it services and you are asking for workaround its **kind-of** stealing (technology, feature, whatever you call it) or piracy

Comment: We are using nothing of theirs. To be clear, they just don't want our presence on the device.

Comment: ok, let it be. sadly, there is no reliable way to prevent this, even after Android 11 changes - there is a new permission for accessing all apps list (or at least checking presence of particular one). btw. I would be very happy when after installing my app all other similar on device would stop working - no competitors, user is kind-of forced to use my app only

Comment: @natghi did you test with Android 11? I wonder whether they violate the Google services `Permissions Declaration Form in Play Console.` I think you can contact Google about this problem since this issue is more about users not about programs. If I'm the mod of Google Play and any program behaves like this without giving any proper explanation, I would ban them forever.

Comment: Think about M.S. Office stops working if you installed LibreOffice or something else. One of you as a user of both can ask Play services as strange behavior of the program..

Comment: No we did not test with android 11. The problem is our users use versions less than that.

Comment: so every app can list your `packageName`. one and only thing you can do is to randomize it for every device instance, pretty hard to achieve... you should also change name, versioning etc. for some random values. thats the only way. it would be easier on Android 11+ to hide from other apps, but still it won't be fully on your hold (as other app may gain full-apps-list permission)

Comment: @snachmsm that's exactly what we did. We randomized the package name. I guess that's all we can do for the moment.

Comment: That's a strange strategy they've chosen to employ. If you randomize the package name how do you manage it all for updates?